# Java validate price with comma or dot and two decimal value

Tags: java, regex

What is the best way and the solution to validate a string that must represents a price value with dot or comma and with maximum two decimal values?

`RegExp`, `java.text.DecimalFormat` or something else?

These values are accepted:

```
1
11

1,05
2,5

1.05
2.5
```

I see these solution but these are not exactly what I want:

[java decimal String format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433958/java-decimal-string-format)

[valdating a 'price' in a jtextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739617/what-is-the-regular-expression-for-valdating-a-price-in-a-jtextfield)

I also try this RegExp `/^(\\d+(?:[\\.\\,]\\d{2})?)$/` but it doesn't work.

Comment: my suggestion would be to go for regexp, especially in the specific format you expect

Comment: regular expressions can help you.

Comment: ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$

with this it must work (addind the contition for the comma

Comment: You are close, you don't need to escape chars in a character class except for a hyphen if it's in the middle. Try `/^\\d+(?:[.,]\\d{2})?$/`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
final String regExp = "[0-9]+([,.][0-9]{1,2})?";
```

It matches 1 or more digits, followed by optional: comma or full stop, followed by 1 or 2 digits.

In Java you can use:

- [`String.matches(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) to simply validate a `String`. For example: `"1.05".matches(regExp)` returns `true`.
- `Pattern` and `Matcher`, which will be [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469244/whats-the-difference-between-string-matches-and-matcher-matches) the [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720191/java-util-regex-importance-of-pattern-compile/1721778#1721778) often you use your regular expression. Example:

  ```
  final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);

  // This can be repeated in a loop with different inputs:
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input); 
  matcher.matches();
  ```

[Test.](http://ideone.com/tRLKxC)

Comment: This whole regex doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is the perfect way i supose, thanks for the info, sometimes i lost in validations too.

Comment: Let me clarify, the OP asked to limit the *decimal* digits to 2 while this one matches infinite decimal digits. Also you're using a character class, so you don't need to escape the dot, and you don't need to use that ugly `|` otherwise you will also match a pipe. Try `12|1212` it will get matched, not really what the OP wanted.

Comment: There are quite some failures here: [] specifies characters, | does not work here. And he wanted two decimal characters. Your regex allows *. The whole regex has to be "turned around".

Comment: Now this will work. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @HamZa You are right, thank you. English is not my native language and my understanding of _decimal digits_ was wrong. I've improved the answer.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk English isn't my native language either +1 :)

Comment: I tested the RegExp "[0-9]+([,.][0-9]{1,2})?" and it works, expected with inputs that start with "," or "."

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this

```
 String str="1,05";
    String[] dotSub=str.split("\\.|,");
    if(dotSub.length==2){
         if(dotSub[1].length()<=2){
             System.out.println("valid price");
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("not a valid price");
         }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("not a valid price");
    }
}
```